# Need help to make one mysql query to get expected result for my requirement

Tags: mysql, join, multi-select

I am facing few issue to write mysql query in my scope to get result. Actually I am getting appropriate result using this existing query but it is not written appropriate way. Here is my query:

```
    SELECT c.ID, c.chn_name,c.chn_logo, 
    (SELECT ID FROM tv_showtime WHERE showtime<='2013-02-18 10:28:35' AND status='Enable' AND chn_id=c.ID ORDER BY ID DESC Limit 0,1) as currentshowid, 
    (SELECT tv_showtime FROM tv_showtime WHERE showtime<='2013-02-18 10:28:35' AND status='Enable' AND chn_id=c.ID ORDER BY ID DESC Limit 0,1) as currentshowtime , 
    (SELECT tv_showtime FROM tv_showtime WHERE showtime >'2013-02-18 10:28:35' AND status='Enable' AND chn_id=c.ID ORDER BY ID ASC Limit 0,1) as nextshowtime 
    FROM tv_channels AS c 
    WHERE c.status="Enable" 
    ORDER BY c.chn_name 
    LIMIT 0,10
```

Here, there are only two tables named as "tv_channels" and "tv_showtime". I need one record for each channel at a time ( for current time). So here suppose 12 channels and approx 30 (may vary foe each channel) records for each channel and I only need to display channels with current show (More clarification: only channels will be displayed which has current show time and/or next show time.)

Problem: I need more field values from "tv_showtime" to display other required values. And if I will use this way then I have to write more inner select query and it will slow down my website to load. So can you suggest or advise any other way to write this query please?

Database table detail:

- tv_channels [ID, chn_name, [other required fields]],
- tv_showtime [ID, chn_id, showtime, show_name, hits, last_ip [and few more fields]]

Please let me know if you will need further detail to get this question.
Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Don't you have a column storing show end time? Are shows going continuously, without any interruptions? If some show on some channel is not 'Enabled', does that mean that previous 'Enabled' show lasts till next 'Enabled' show, covering disabled show's time as well?

Comment: @Olexa Sorry for too late to reply. you are correct. there is not any show end time. It shows current show until there is not any next show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another asked, but you didnt respond to an "end time" for each show, I had to go on the premise that the show time was when it started.  That said, how do you determine which is the current show running for a given channel based on CURTIME() (instead of fixed time value).

Get each channel and the MAXIMUM SHOW Time that exists PRIOR TO the current time...

Likewise, how to get the NEXT Show?  Get each channel with the MINIMUM SHOW time that STARTS AFTER the current time.

So, if I had the following records for 1 channels and the current time is 2:15pm

```
Channel   ShowTime   Show_Name
1         12:30pm    Show "X"
1         01:00pm    Show "B"
1         01:30pm    Show "C"     
1         02:00pm    Show "D"      <-  Current Show
1         02:30pm    Show "Y"      <-  Next Show
1         03:00pm    Show "Z"
```

The current show running is the latest one PRIOR to 2:15 (Show "D" starting at 2pm)
and the NEXT Show is first AFTER current time (Show "Y" starting at 2:30pm).  The above will work even if the rows are not in sequential order as I am using MIN() and MAX() respectively to get the time.

So, I start with the channel table and do a left-join to each separate pre-aggregate query for detecting the current show and next show times respectively and join on the channel ID which each COULD return at most one record --- provided there IS a record within qualified WHERE CURTIME() consideration.

From THAT, I am re-joining THOSE result sets back to the actual tv schedule table AGAIN, but this time, on the channel AND the time that matched the corresponding current or next time.

So now, I have everything lined up ready to go with respective aliases for content.  Now, I just grab the columns I want to present.

Since the joins are all LEFT-JOINs, each side COULD have NULL values, so you might want to adjust the query to prevent nulls using COALESCE(), such as I've sampled...

```
SELECT
      TC.ID,
      TC.Chn_Name,
      TC.Chn_Logo,
      COALESCE( CurShowTimeDetail.ShowTime, 'no time' )  CurShowTime,
      COALESCE( CurShowTimeDetail.Show_Name, '' )        CurShowName,
      COALESCE( CurShowTimeDetail.Hits, 0 )              CurHits,
      COALESCE( NextShowTimeDetail.ShowTime, 'no time' ) NextShowTime,
      COALESCE( NextShowTimeDetail.Show_Name, '' )       NextShowName,
      COALESCE( NextShowTimeDetail.Hits, 0 )             NextHits
   from 
      TV_Channels TC

         LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
                           ST.chn_id, 
                           MAX( ST.showtime ) CurShowTime
                        from
                           tv_showtime ST
                        where
                           ST.ShowTime < CURTIME()
                        group by
                           ST.chn_id ) CurrentShow
            ON TC.ID = CurrentShow.Chn_ID
            LEFT JOIN tv_showtime CurShowTimeDetail
               ON CurrentShow.Chn_ID = CurShowTimeDetail.Chn_ID
               AND CurrentShow.CurShowTime = CurShowTimeDetail.ShowTime

         LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
                           ST.chn_id, 
                           MIN( ST.showtime ) NextShowTime
                        from
                           tv_showtime ST
                        where
                           ST.ShowTime > CURTIME()
                        group by
                           ST.chn_id ) NextShow
            ON TC.ID = NextShow.Chn_ID
            LEFT JOIN tv_showtime NextShowTimeDetail
               ON NextShow.Chn_ID = NextShowTimeDetail.Chn_ID
               AND NextShow.NextShowTime = NextShowTimeDetail.ShowTime
```

Comment: Hi DRapp, Thanks a lots for your help to optimize my query. In this query i can select number of fields for currentshow. Thank you again. It saved my lots. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To select last (first) records from a table by some order, you may `LEFT JOIN` the table with itself as *any* next (previous) element, and add a condition that there is *no* such element.

```
SELECT c.ID, c.chn_name, c.chn_logo
  , curr_sh.ID AS currentshowid, curr_sh.showtime AS currentshowtime -- Continue with desired columns
  , next_sh.showtime AS nextshowtime -- Continue with desired columns
  FROM tv_channels AS c 
    LEFT JOIN tv_showtime AS curr_sh
      ON curr_sh.chn_id = c.ID
        AND curr_sh.showtime <= '2013-02-18 10:28:35'
        AND curr_sh.status='Enable'
    LEFT JOIN tv_showtime AS curr_next_sh
      ON curr_next_sh.chn_id = curr_sh.chn_id
        AND curr_next_sh.showtime >  curr_sh.showtime
        AND curr_next_sh.showtime <= '2013-02-18 10:28:35'
        AND curr_next_sh.status = 'Enable'
    LEFT JOIN tv_showtime AS next_sh
      ON next_sh.chn_id = c.ID
        AND next_sh.showtime > '2013-02-18 10:28:35'
        AND next_sh.status='Enable'
    LEFT JOIN tv_showtime AS next_prev_sh
      ON next_prev_sh.chn_id = next_sh.chn_id
        AND next_prev_sh.showtime <  next_sh.showtime
        AND next_prev_sh.showtime > '2013-02-18 10:28:35'
        AND next_prev_sh.status = 'Enable'
  WHERE c.status = 'Enable'
    AND curr_next_sh.ID IS NULL -- This gives us only the latest current show
    AND next_prev_sh.ID IS NULL -- This gives us only the earliest next show
    AND (curr_sh.ID IS NOT NULL OR next_sh.ID IS NOT NULL) -- This gives us 'which has current show time and/or next show time'
  ORDER BY c.chn_name 
  LIMIT 0,10
```

But I'm not sure about performance, and whether this solution is optimal.

Comment: Hi Olexa, Thanks a lot. this query is working perfectly as per my requirement. Thanks a lot again.